# Android call getView on every element in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I understand for efficiency, android only calls the getView method on certain elements in a ListView (those visible, or clicked on, etc.)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView

For my custom ArrayAdapter implementation, however, it is important that getView be called for every element in the list (regardless of whether or not it is visible).

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Why would you want that ?

Comment: If they are not visible, why call the method?

Comment: I have some Bitmaps inside of the objects within my listview, which are loaded in getView, however I need them elsewhere on the screen too.  The observed behaviour is they load on the screen (elsewhere) only when I scroll to them in the listview.

Comment: Load them elsewhere and pass them to the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve? GetView is called with every item, is up to you to implement a ViewHolder or something like that in order to re-use the view or not. However, you should do.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some Bitmaps inside of the objects within my listview, which
>   are loaded in getView, however I need them elsewhere on the screen
>   too. The observed behaviour is they load on the screen (elsewhere)
>   only when I scroll to them in the listview.

Simple solution would be to load your images elsewhere and as soon as you load them you can update your list adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` .

> Note : You cannot invoke getView() for those list items which are not
>   visible.

Comment: "You cannot invoke getView() for those list items which are not visible." - Sure ya can. You can call `getView()` directly on the Adapter. It's just needlessly costly, in this case.

Comment: I agree with you. What I meant was by design you can't.

Comment: @MikeM. that is what I ended up doing - iterating over the entire list, and calling getView() on each one.  A slight hack, but justifiable in this specific application (and preferable to the more long-winded solution)

Comment: @DavidFerris long but perfect solution. called getview in for loop at only position 0 in getView method. after for loop again call getview for position 0. There is no mixing about bitmaps anymore.